# AJAX URL update

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

Im sure there is a simple solution for this but im having issues,

I have an external ajax.js file that has an AJAX call like so:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function( data, status )
```

above the AJAX call I have got two global variables called ticker and url like so:

```
 var ticker = 'AAPL'
 var url = 'http://blahblahblah' + ticker
```

In my HTML file I have got an input box where the user types in a ticker symbol (e.g. GOOG) and clicks a button that would update the ticker variable so that the AJAX call is done again with the new URL.

```
 <form id="form">
            <h3>Enter the ticker symbol of the company you wish to view:</h3>
            <input type="text" id="userInput">
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js">
        <script>
        function myFunction()
        {
                //old value
                alert(ticker);

                ticker = document.getElementById('userInput').value;

                //new value
                alert(ticker);
        }
        </script>
```

This code changes the ticker variable but the AJAX call is still being performed with the old ticker url. I think its not being assigned properly? Im very new to AJAX but I cant find any tutorials online that explain this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the code you've posted, your ajax routine is only being called when the page is loaded, which explains why only the default url / ticker is shown in the results.

You need to wrap the ajax routine in a function and call it after the user has inputted a symbol:

In your ajax.js file:

```
function getSymbolInfo(ticker) { // consider passing ticker to this function instead of using a global var
    $.ajax({
        url: url + ticker,
        success: function( data, status ) {
           // show results
        }
    });
}
```

And from MyFunction:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var ticker = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    getSymbolInfo(ticker);

}
```

Comment: I have edited my code so that it is in this format but the AJAX call is still not being performed. Do you have any suggestions? http://jsfiddle.net/BPPyz/

Comment: After reworking your Fiddle a bit, I get a an error that a POST request must be used, but after supplying the ajax routine with type: 'post', I get the same error. Perhaps the url needs to be a different one than you are using. New jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/TxYNU/

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable in Javascript, meaning that url is going to be constant, even if you change ticker. Do this instead:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http:/blah" + ticker,
        success: function(data, status) {}
    });
});
```

EDIT: Now that I think about it, it has nothing to do with strings being immutable. Doing `url = "http:/" + ticker` doesn't create a closure with the value of `ticker`, it simply creates a new string value and stores it in `url`. After the new value is created, it's not linked to `ticker` in any way.

Comment: I have tried the method you have suggested but it still does not work I am just gettin an error.