# HighStocks not updating URL

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp, highcharts

I posted this question [AJAX URL update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838447/ajax-url-update) as I thought the problem with my code was with AJAX but I think this could be an issue with HighStocks.

I have an external .js file with these functions:

```
    //uses AJAX call to retrieve data and then creates the chart with the data
    function createChart(ticker) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://...' + ticker + '....com',
            success: function (data, status) {
            //chart is rendered in here
            }

    //gets the user inputted ticker symbol from a HTML input box
    // and passes to chart function
    function getTicker() {
        var ticker = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
        createChart(ticker);
    }
```

My HTML file just has a simple form with an input box and a button that when clicked calls the getTicker function. For some reason the chart is not being created and the AJAX call doesnt seem to work.

Is this something with HighStocks maybe? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE** Thank you for the suggestions, I have attempted to use JSONP but the chart still does not load. Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

```
        var closePrices = new Array();
    var dateArray = new Array();
    var timeStampArray = new Array();
    var timeClose = new Array();

function jsonCallback(data, ticker) {

            console.log( data );

            //Put all the closing prices into an array and convert to floats
            for(var i=0; i < data.query.results.quote.length; i++)
            {
                closePrices[i] = parseFloat( data.query.results.quote[i].Close );
            }

            //displays the values in the closePrices array
            console.log( closePrices );

            //Put all the dates into an array
            for(var i=0; i < data.query.results.quote.length; i++)
            {
                dateArray[i] = data.query.results.quote[i].date;
            }

            //Convert all the dates into JS Timestamps
            for(var i=0; i < dateArray.length; i++)
            {
                timeStampArray[i] = new Date( dateArray[i] ).getTime();
            }


            for(var i=0; i<data.query.results.quote.length; i++)
            {
                   timeClose.push( [timeStampArray[i], closePrices[i]] );
            }

            timeClose = timeClose.reverse();
            console.log ( timeClose );

            //displays the dateArray
            console.log( dateArray );
            console.log( timeStampArray );

            // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : ticker + ' Stock Price'
            },

            series : [{
                name : ticker,
                data: timeClose,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
}

function createChart() {  

    var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22' + ticker +'%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222013-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222013-02-25%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=?';
    //Ajax call retrieves the data from Yahoo! Finance API
    $.ajax( url, {
        dataType: "jsonp",  
        success: function(data, status){
            console.log(status);
            jsonCallback(data, ticker);
        },
        error: function( jqXHR, status, error ) {
            console.log( 'Error: ' + error );
        }
    });
}


//Function to get ticker symbol from input box.
function getTicker() {
        var ticker = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
        createChart(ticker);
    }
```

Comment: What format is the data that you are attempting to pull back? This looks like it may well be an issue with the Same Origin Policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy -- something that often prevents an ajax pull from working unless you are using JSONP or SCRIPT as the format for the data.

Comment: Im getting JSON data, does this mean I cannot change the AJAX url to retrieve different company data? Thats annoying.

Comment: You need to use JSONPin that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jeffrey Blake and Pawel Fus for your suggestions. Using JSONP I was able to get my program functioning correctly :)